# Using OpenOffice.org SDK in Netbeans 6.7

Tags: java, openoffice.org, netbeans6.7

So I have this mindless copy-pasting task from OpenOffice documents to another OpenOffice doc, a spreadsheet. I thought this would be an awesome chance to save time and do the cool thing and write a small program to do all my copying and pasting for me (it's a huge amount).

So I find out that OpenOffice has this API/SDK for just this kind of thing. It seems as if it only works with Java 1.5/1.6 and Netbeans 6.7 or earlier, as well as Eclipse. Since they have a plugin built for Netbeans I installed Netbeans 6.7 and the plugin following their online guide (http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/OpenOffice_NetBeans_Integration).

I'm able to almost create a new OpenOffice project and get started and feel happy, except I keep getting some kind of Java error in Netbeans EVERY time I try to create the project.

The exact error I get is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openoffice.extensions.config.LibraryManager.getLibraryName(LibraryManager.java:176)
    at org.openoffice.extensions.config.ConfigurationSettings.getLibraryName(ConfigurationSettings.java:280)
    at org.openoffice.extensions.util.ProjectCreator.updateWizardDescriptor(ProjectCreator.java:219)
    at org.openoffice.extensions.util.ProjectCreator.createAddon(ProjectCreator.java:170)
    at org.openoffice.extensions.projecttemplates.addon.AddOnWizardIterator.instantiate(AddOnWizardIterator.java:146)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard$InstantiatingIteratorBridge.instantiate(TemplateWizard.java:1018)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.handleInstantiate(TemplateWizard.java:588)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.instantiateNewObjects(TemplateWizard.java:409)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIterImpl.instantiate(TemplateWizardIterImpl.java:248)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIteratorWrapper.instantiate(TemplateWizardIteratorWrapper.java:161)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.callInstantiateOpen(WizardDescriptor.java:1527)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.callInstantiate(WizardDescriptor.java:1481)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.access$1700(WizardDescriptor.java:127)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener$2$1.run(WizardDescriptor.java:2052)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener$2.run(WizardDescriptor.java:2101)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$7.run(WizardDescriptor.java:1413)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.lazyValidate(WizardDescriptor.java:1453)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.access$1300(WizardDescriptor.java:127)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener.actionPerformed(WizardDescriptor.java:2108)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl$ProxyListener.invoke(WeakListenerImpl.java:451)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6414)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6179)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2083)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4776)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2141)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4619)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4280)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4210)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2127)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2489)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:690)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:687)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:104)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:1049)
    at java.awt.Dialog$3.run(Dialog.java:1101)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1099)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.superShow(NbPresenter.java:985)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.doShow(NbPresenter.java:1019)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.run(NbPresenter.java:1007)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.run(NbPresenter.java:115)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.doEventAccess(Mutex.java:1355)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:268)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.show(NbPresenter.java:992)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1615)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1567)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:843)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:984)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.instantiateImpl(TemplateWizard.java:495)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.instantiate(TemplateWizard.java:362)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.actions.NewProject$2.run(NewProject.java:139)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:685)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:104)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Seeing the NULL pointer and reference to configuring an extension (the OpenOffice stuff), I'm figuring something just isn't set up right.
What I can't figure out is -- what is it that I'm missing? My Mac is set to use Java 1.6, recognized via the terminal and causing no bugs anywhere else. Netbeans works fine and the plugin is installed and indicates both the OpenOffice installation and SDK source I linked it are good to go.

Has anyone by chance used this API before or have an idea on what I'm missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

*EDIT*
Netbeans gives me a different summary when I consider reporting it, and what I've embedded above is the "details":

```
A java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception has occurred.
Please report this at http://www.netbeans.org/community/issues.html,
including a copy of your messages.log file as an attachment.
The messages.log file is located in your /Users/bailey/.netbeans/6.7/var/log folder.
```

Comment: If anyone has been or is looking at this, I still have not found the solution. I ended up solving the base problem a different way.

I have, however, also learned that the way OS X handles JAVA installations starting ~ 10.8 is a little quirky.

While I am not entirely clear on the details, JAVA 6 and JAVA 7 together often have issues. So if you follow a path similar to mine, be cautious and keep that in mind.